# GWT security: web.xml filter vs overriding processPost() in RemoteServiceServlet

Tags: security, gwt

I have a GWT application that resides within a single web page, which I believe is fairly typical. I am in the process of securing it, and I need advice on choosing a proper approach. My ultimate intention is to check for presence of authenticated session on every gwtrpc server call.

In the past when dealing with servlet/JSP-based web application, I used **filter** and **filter-mapping** definitions in web.xml. And that worked like a charm considering that such applications usually consisted of many web pages, and redirection to a login page went right along with it. But in case of GWT and its often-used single screen nature, I feel that overriding **RemoteServiceServlet**'s ***processPost()*** function may be a better approach. My intention would be to check for presence of an existing session, and then throw an appropriate exception if needed. The client would then react accordingly (i.e. login popup, etc) by determining the course of action based on whatever exception is thrown back to it.

I am aware of other existing solutions such as Spring security, but I would really like to hear opinions on my idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should check for an authenticated session yourself. Let the application container deal with that. Of course, in order to do that, you will need a login-config section and security constraints in your web.xml file.

A good way to secure specific parts of your application is to check (prior to the actual display of the screen) if the current user is allowed to. From your remote servlet you can call `getThreadLocalRequest().getUserPrincipal()` to get the actual user (null if not authenticated) and `getThreadLocalRequest().isUserInRole("admin")` to make the autorization.

Hope this is helpful for you !

Comment: i am using an external security repository that i am connecting to manually, so i must check for session presence manually. i am not relying on app server-based security.

Comment: Still, you should try to avoid to mix application security and application logic. It's a bad idea. You could try to define your own server login module (JSR-196). That way, you can handle security once and build several applications without having to think about that. Which application server are you using ?